# How to cast a (java.lang.Class) Class to a Class obtained with reflection

Tags: jsf, reflection, primefaces, java.lang.class

I'm trying to build a module for managing my database's catalogues like: country, enterprises, users etc. The user is supposed to select the catalog from a combobox and the system is supposed to display a table with the principal columns (not null in the database and some predefined by me). From the 3 objectives I have only achieved 2: 
1.- get the `@NotNull` fields from the Entity Classes after selecting the catalogue using reflection
2.-display the table with dynamic columns retrieving them from the above also. 
 But number 3 is giving me trouble. The thing is, I used this folling code in the view for displaying columns dynamically (based on the `@NotNull` fields I stored in an object)  ,(https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml):

```
<p:dataTable  id="conceptos" var="pojo" value="#{catalogoMB.comocombo}>
<p:columns value="#{catalogoMB.columns}" var="column" 
columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{pojo[column.property]}" filterBy="#
{pojo[column.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{pojo[column.property]}" />
</p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

So for example, in a normal way, without reflection the code above will work like this: 
 ***comocombo*** will have this properties: name, value, id; and my array of columns will be the same: name, value, id...
The thing is, `comocombo`  is a  `List<Object>` object where I store field's reflection class values, which returns java.lang.class instead of the instance of the EntityClass although I managed to invoke setter and getter from an Object instance of that class (combito) -supposedly- 
so when I try to display `pojo[column.property]`-> comocombo["id"], comocombo["name"] or comocombo["value"] it sends me an exception saying that `java.lang.class` doesn't have this any properties....How can I reach them? I've read about `Map<String, String>` and of `.cast()` But I'm not sure this could be the way.

```
public void populateT(){ 
comocombo=new ArrayList<>();
Object tt ;
y = tabla.get(tabla.size()-1).getConcpetos(); //result of query type: 
FindAll from the entity Class 
try{
Class combito= Class.forName("sipe.services."+ catName); //the "path" of the 
Entity Classes
for (Integer j=0; j<y.size()-1; j++){
tt=y.get(j);
            for (Integer i=0; i< tabla.size()-1; i++){
            tucampo=minustomayus(y.get(j).getClass().getDeclaredField(tabla.get(i).getNombre_c()).getName()); //tabla.get(i).getNombre_c()-> here I've stored the @NotNull properties' names (countryid, countryname...) whic are the same in  columns = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();  (catalogoMB.columns in the view) 
            Class cls= Class.forName("sipe.services."+ catName);
            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("get"+tucampo); // for example "countryid" -> getCountryid              
            Class<?> type = null;
            for (Method methods : combito.getDeclaredMethods())
            { //Here I'm trying to invoke setter of the Entity Class in order to store its values..
              //equivalent to: if o is an instance of Entity Class Country: Country o = new Country(); o.setCountryid(2);
                if (methods.getName().contains("set"+tucampo)){
                type=method.getReturnType();
                methods.invoke(combito.newInstance(),method.invoke(tt));
             }
            }
```

Comment: if i should understand this,you want to load your data-table columns dynamically based on the selected value in a combo-box where the values of your combo-box are entity classes?

Comment: Yes @Kaizen, I've already achieved this: add columns dynamically to my datatable...according to each entity Class selected...I faced a problem when trying to display data according to those columns because my object is a java.lang.Class (effect of the reflection) and my variable on the p:dataTable doesn´t reach the properties...

Comment: you could answer your question and accept :)

Comment: @Kaizen, well not really hehe, what I wan to is to avoid this: `serverError: class javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException The class 'java.lang.Class' does not have the property 'id'.` although the object says it is an instance of the reflection class it cannot reach the properties so the data is never display... that's my issue; I was trying to give the most background I could give to the question :P

Comment: Roger that posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got mine to work this way, hope it helps

```
 private void createDynamicColumns(){
            //split column templates
            String[] columnKeys = columnTemplate.split(" ");
            //set first list to null
            //this should be a List with no type specified
            //eg List objects = new ArrayList<>();
            //since you will dynamically populate it based on what the user selects from combobox
            objects = null;
            //clear columns
            columns.clear();
            //create a class from combobox selection
            Class<?> forName = Class.forName("pathToClass." + comboboxSelection);
            //get declared fields in that class
            List<Field> asList = Arrays.asList(forName.getDeclaredFields());
            //for each columkeys
            //if method.getName() can be found in columnKeys
            //add that columnKey to the new columnList;
            for(int i =0;i< asList.size();i++)
                for (String columnKey : columnKeys) {
                    String fieldName = asList.get(i).getName();
                    if (columnKey.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
                        columns.add(fieldName);
                    }
                }

          //fetch from the database the objects list
           objects = DAO.findAll();
        }
```

and facelets page

```
<p:dataTable var="object" value="#{backingBean.objects}">                    
        <p:columns value="#{BackingBean.columns}" var="column">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{object[column]}" />
        </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Remember to deal with exceptions

Comment: *claps claps* Thank you!! I really doesn't implement the solution as you did it but this: `value="#{backingBean.objects}"` WAS JUST WHAT I NEEDED!!! =D I'm very thankful and happy :D; I change this line on mine: `<p:dataTable  id="conceptos" var="pojo" value="#{catalogoMB.y}>` y is my list of objects that I got from the "findAll" query and it worked!! thank you

Comment: this y:`y = tabla.get(tabla.size()-1).getConcpetos(); //result of query type:`